# How to remove rows of a word table that contains a string using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

***this code remove all the rows of the table, but i want to remove a specific rows(if rows contain for example number 2)***

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTP;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTc;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\TMPL.docx");


    XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fis);

    List<XWPFTable> tables = doc.getTables();
    XWPFTable table = tables.get(0);

    XWPFTableRow[] rows = table.getRows().toArray(new XWPFTableRow[0]);

    for (int r = 0; r < rows.length; r++) {
        if (r > 0) {
            XWPFTableRow row = rows[r];
            CTTc[] cells = row.getCtRow().getTcList().toArray(new CTTc[0]);
            for (int c = 0; c < cells.length; c++) {
                CTTc cTTc = cells[c];

                //clear only the paragraphs in the cell, keep cell styles
                cTTc.setPArray(new CTP[] {CTP.Factory.newInstance()});
                cells[c] = cTTc;
            }
            row.getCtRow().setTcArray(cells);
            //System.out.println(row.getCtRow());
        }
    }

    doc.write(new FileOutputStream("new document.docx"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you find a row containing the number 2, you can use the method `table.removeRow(i)` (documented [here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html#removeRow-int-)) to remove the complete row at position `i`.